# what does the expression stand for?

Tags: c, printf

What does the `0x%08x` mean in the below statement?

```
printf("\t\t\t[in func3] i @ 0x%08x = %d\n", &i, i);
```

Does it mean prepend the result with `0x` and give a 8 digit hexadecimal value?

Comment: It means to print in lowercase hexadecimal (`%...x`), 4 bytes wide (8 digits, `08`), with leading zeros, with `0x` just before.

Comment: So yes, your guess is correct and can be confirmed by the documentation.

Comment: You should read the documentation on the `printf` format strings. There's ample documentation that covers this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a lookup failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\t\t\t[in func3] i @ 0x%08x = %d\n", &i, i);
```

There are two format-strings here, and corresponding arguments:

`%08x` in `0x%08x`: Print an `int`/`unsigned` with 8 hexadecimal digits including leading zeroes (after the `0x`).
`%#08x` would be simpler for the same.

Anyway, it is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984) as a pointer is not an `int`.
Use `%p` to print a data-pointer, after conversion to `void*`, `char*`, `unsigned char*` or `signed char*`.

The other one is `%d` for printing an `int` in standard decimal notation, so let's hope `i` is really one.

For reference, here the man-page for `printf`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yes. Added a sentence giving the only valid specifier for pointers.